# assigning values to array of string in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

In C++ why does this works

```
string strarr[10]={"hello","harshit"};
```

but not this

```
string strarr[10];
strarr[]={"hello","harshit"};
```

What's the reason for this ?

Comment: There are many reasons why the second one wouldn't work. The question is, what would you expect that syntax to mean?

Comment: I'd suggest you to read this: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: Maybe you mean string strarr[]={"hello","harshit"}; ? This works.

Comment: Even if you repair the syntax (`strarr[]` is completly wrong) you can't assign to arrays.

Comment: the reason is given by the compiler in its error message. above all why write such poor code?

Answer (score 1):

Like we can't just say in English "correct horse battery staple" and expect it to mean something we must also conform to the C++ language the way it was defined.

If you want to initialize items in the array after the array is defined you have to initialize them one by one:

```
strarr[0] = "hello";
strarr[1] = "harshit";
```

That's what the C++ standard says, and that's what we all must do.

Comment: How did you guess my password? oO

Answer (score 0):

```
string strarr[10]={"hello","harshit"};
```

is initializing a string array with some values which is valid and does not seems unlogical.

---

```
strarr[]={"hello","harshit"};
```

This is not valid at all. `[]` are not allowed here from the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can call "Uniform initialization" only when constructing new object;
why? question to C++ comittet